# Google Translate Api sudenly start returning 'Daily Limit Exeeded' but in Developer Console all is OK

Tags: google-translate

We paid the service and so far We have been using it without any problem.
Today it has started to stop working and returns the error:

error: {errors: [{domain: "usageLimits", reason: "dailyLimitExceeded", message: "Daily Limit Exceeded"}],…}
code: 403
errors: [{domain: "usageLimits", reason: "dailyLimitExceeded", message: "Daily Limit Exceeded"}]
0: {domain: "usageLimits", reason: "dailyLimitExceeded", message: "Daily Limit Exceeded"}
domain: "usageLimits"
message: "Daily Limit Exceeded"
reason: "dailyLimitExceeded"
message: "Daily Limit Exceeded"

But in Developer Console all is correct and today We have 100% cuote still free.

What could be the problem, we can provide the necessary data to help detect the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: experience exceeding Google search usageLimits here (both mechanically and by hand!). The odometer keeps track of your browser particulars, so one browser can still surf while another is blocked. Not a real answer; someone will help both of us...

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting the 10,000 chars/100seconds/user limit.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956521/1880872).